# double-dash command line options instead of getopt

Tags: c, command-line

How can I accept a command line argument this way:

```
./a.out --printall
```

so that inside my program, I have something like

```
if (printall) {
  // do something
}
```

I don't want to do this:

```
if (argc == 2)
  //PRINTALL exists
```

since my program can have multiple command line options:

```
./a.out --printread
./a.out --printwrite
```

Secondly, I don't want to use getopt , such that the command becomes

```
./a.out -printall 1
```

I just find `./a.out --printall` cleaner than `./a.out -printall 1`

Edit: 
I have seen programs that do this:

```
./a.out --help
```

I wonder how they work.

Comment: The preprocessor cannot interact with variables at run-time in this way. It is impossible. The preprocess runs before the program is compiled.

Comment: Please look at my edit. You're using the editor in the worst possible way. You should never need to insert `<br>` tags, and you should be avoiding the use of back-ticks for code except for inline statements.

Comment: Ok, assume I remove the ifdefs. Is there a way I can accept the argument using --? How do programs that provide a --help option work>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(About the argument parsing part of the question:)

You will need `getopt_long()` from `<unistd.h>`. This is a GNU extension.

For greater portability, you might consider Boost [program options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/program_options.html), though that's a compiled library.

Comment: The getopt_long() extension is available as source and it's no big deal to add it to one's application, as there are no (almost?) dependencies.

Comment: @alk: Fair enough, I never looked at the source code. Sounds like a good idea.

Comment: +1: This is the answer to the question the OP _meant_ to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Command line arguments cannot be used to trigger conditional compilation. The program has already been compiled before the program is run.

This is a very pedantic answer. For command-line options in general, see Kerrek SB's answer.

Comment: Can I use arguments provided using -- without conditional compilation? Similar to the way programs that provide a --help option work?

Comment: Yes. Your program needs to be compiled with support for all possible options. Use a library like getopt_long (see Kerrek SB's answer) to parse out the option flags from the command line. Then at runtime, conditional logic (if/else, switch, etc) decides what code to execute passed on the options parsed.