# C convert command line argument to different command line argument

Tags: c

I would like to know if it is possible to convert command line argument option to another command line argument option. I am trying to build a new agrument option from the combination of 2 other command line argument. For example, I am using `#include<getopt.h>`, and imagine you have a command line tool that does the following:

```
./app --run "python" --pkg "pandas"
(Which run in the terminal python -m install pandas)
```

Now I want to create a new option in my c program app called 'install' which does the same as above.

```
./app --install "pandas"
```

In the C code I want --install "pandas" to be "rewritten" or redirected to --run "python" --pkg "pandas"

It is essentially parsing all options and arguments, matching them against a pattern and converting the user input to another combination of user input already implemented at the C level.

Please let me know if it is not clear. Sorry in advance if my english is not clear.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Create a function for handling `--run "python" --pkg "pandas"`. Then call it for `--install "pandas"`. No need to modify the arguments (which is not easy, the `argv` array have a fixed size that you can't change).

Comment: Please show what you've tried, and what problems you encountered in the process.

Comment: I don't know if I got it wrong but, shouldn't handle `--install` in the same way you handle `--run "python" --pkg` do the trick?

Comment: It is your program. Write it to behave the way you want it to behave. If you cannot do that, you have not learned to program well enough yet, and the solution is to keep learning. You have not described what prevents you from writing the desired program well enough that anybody can give you any specific advice.

Comment: `getopt` does not have to be called with the argument list from `main`. You can construct your own argument list and parse it with `getopt` if you want. Also if you want to use `getopt` on both the argument list from `main` and a separate, constructed argument list, you can "reset" `getopt` inbetween by setting `optind` to 1. Constructing a new argument list is not the best way to deal with your underlying requirement though, as mentioned in the other comments and answers.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know if it is possible to convert command line argument option to another command line argument option.

You are fully in control of how your program, having parsed its command line arguments, responds to those arguments.  In that sense, yes, you can make it behave the same way when `--install` `pandas` is presented as it does when `--run` `python` `--pkg` `pandas` is presented.  The details are up to you.

You imply that you are using `getopt()` for argument processing.  Apparently GNU's version. Inasmuch as you are also in control of the argument count and argument vector passed to `getopt()`, it is conceivable that you could pre-analyze the ones received by `main()`, and create new ones that (say) replace `--install` `pandas` with `--run` `python` `--pkg` `pandas`.  Then you could feed the rewritten arguments to `getopt()`.  This is a more literal "conver[sion]" of the command line arguments, but pretty much no one does this, because it means you have to parse the options twice.  It's much easier to do it the other way.

There is no way to tell `getopt()` to perform such conversions automatically.

> **In the C code** I want --install "pandas" to be "rewritten" or redirected to --run "python" --pkg "pandas"
>
> It is essentially parsing all options and arguments, matching them against a pattern and converting the user input to another combination of user input already implemented at the C level.

(emphasis added)

It is *all* implemented at the C level.  Yes, you can do it with minimal code duplication, if that's what you mean.  There are several way to do that.  One might be to write a function that handles these kinds of arguments, put all the work there, and have the code handling the results of your option parsing call that from however many places it needs to do.  There are other possibilities.

Of course, you could also consider just not providing redundant options.  Option redundancy does sometimes make sense, but I'm not seeing a benefit in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Answer already given elsewhere:

> You will need getopt_long() from <unistd.h>. This is a GNU extension.

See
[double-dash command line options instead of getopt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757986/double-dash-command-line-options-instead-of-getopt)